# Style error when importing element ui into nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, element-ui

I'm trying to import element UI into Nuxt.js and on their twitter account they linked to glitch (https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nuxt-element-ui?path=layouts/default.vue:1:0) that has the important files listed. In the default.vue you it has this listed

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>

<style src="element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css"></style>
```

I imported element ui into my nuxt project by running:

```
 npm i element-ui --save nuxt
```

searched for index.css in the folder and copy-pasted that link as a source to the style src (node_modules\element-ui\lib\theme-chalk\index.css) for the default.vue file but I am getting an error that it can not locate it.

I also tried to use the cdn style file from element ui's website:

```
https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css
```

Both of them are resulting in "Module not found"

What am I doing wrong? Any other place that has anything listed on how to import element ui into nuxt?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your style, you can import it like this:

```html
<style>
  @import '~element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'
</style>
```

But you can also import it directly from your javascript:

```js
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Global CSS should be defined in `css` section of `nuxt.config`

e.g.

```
module.exports = {
  css: [
    { src: '~/assets/index.css', lang: 'scss' },
  ],
｝
```

and CDN stylesheet should be defined in `head.links`

```
  head: {
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css' },
    ],
  },
```

Read:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head

Comment: Thank you for the links and the examples. I'm still a little bit confused. Even with bootstrap I have not been able to install it via CDN (I keep getting an error). I went to the head.link and replaced the href you provided with bootstrap CDN and it failed. 

Unlike Angular you can't just use bootstrap or element by pasting the CDN the head, right?